# Resolution wrong in 16.04 installed in Mac OS X

Tags: display, parallels

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my MacBook Pro Retina 2015 with Parallels.
When I play Ubuntu the resolution is only 800x600. I try to install the Intel-graphic-tools, create the resolution by terminal with the command "xrandr" and I try to follow all the guide that I found on the web but I don't resolve the issue.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Parallels is a virtualization software. Like others the hardware support is given by the virtualization tools.

Go to Virtual Machine then Install Parallels Tools and when it is done reboot the VM.

[Source](https://forum.parallels.com/threads/display-resolution-for-ubuntu-14-10-under-parallels-9.327485/#post-767144)

Comment: The toolbox is correctly installed but the problem remain.